# IIS 10.0 Detailed Errr - 404.15 - NOT found

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post, get

I got this error when i tried to add large value in the text box and tried to save it . I am using ajax get method. 
 My controller

```
public ActionResult UpDateDataSetDetails(int workItemId, string dataSetDateStamp, int cycle, string reference, string feed, string source, string target, int lineStart, string extension, string note, int? fileContentId, string dataFixes, int oldWorkitemId)
{
    EditDataSetVM editDataSetVM = new EditDataSetVM();

    //Abandoning the current work Item, and logging error if there are any.
    if (oldWorkitemId != 0)
    {
        actionErrors = _dataSetService.ProcessDataSet(new int[] { oldWorkitemId }, 99, User.UserName); // 99 is assigned in _State (Static Data marked) table as Processing abandoned
        TempData["message"] = actionErrors.ToList();
    }
    editDataSetVM.SuccessMessage = this._dataSetService.UpdateDataSet(workItemId, dataSetDateStamp, cycle, reference, feed, source, target, User.Identity.Name, lineStart, extension.ToLower(), note, fileContentId, dataFixes, oldWorkitemId);
    return Json(editDataSetVM.SuccessMessage.ToString());
}
```

My ajax method is

```
function updateDataSet(workItemID, dataSetDateStamp, cycle, reference, feed, source, target, lineStart, extension, note, fileContentId, dataFixes, oldWorkitemId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/DataSet/UpDateDataSetDetails",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { "workItemId": workItemID, "dataSetDateStamp": dataSetDateStamp, "cycle": cycle, "reference": reference, "feed": feed, "source": source, "target": target, "lineStart": lineStart, "extension": extension, "note": note, "fileContentId": fileContentId, "dataFixes": dataFixes, "oldWorkitemId": oldWorkitemId },
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == "Update Succeeded") {
                $("#btnViewDataSet").click();
            }
            else {
                $("div.toshow").show();
                $('#lblUpdateDataSetResult').html('Following error(s) occured:<br\>' + data);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You not stringifying your data, so you need to remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Comment: No that dint help

Comment: Remove it! A GET has no body so its pointless. But its a GET and there is a limit on the size of the query string and once you exceed it an exception is thrown. You need to use a POST instead (and for that you do need to remove it)

Comment: I changed it to POST and my intial problem is solved ,but still the textbox doesnot show the whole data which was intially saved.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comment and you have not even shown your textbox, or how you pass its value to your js function, or even which property your referring to. If you have used `$.(yourTextBox).val()` to get its contents, then it will be passed to your controller, but I have no idea what you mean by _ does not show the whole data which was initially saved_

Comment: ok so the scenario is to add some data in the textarea for and when we click on the save button . It gets saved. and next time when we open the pop up and see the textarea for we should be able to see the whole data. But now its being trimmed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152227/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-catwoman).

Comment: datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                $('#modalWrapperNew').html(data);

                $('#modaleditdataset').modal('show');
            }

Comment: For the love of all things good and holy: *use a view model*. That's half your problem right there. That's a stupid amount of parameters for your action to accept, it if you don't match them all, you'll get a 404 because MVC won't be able to activate the method. Put all your parameters into a class as properties, and then simply accept that class as a param to your action.